# C# XElement: Node Formatting with HTML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm extracting XML node from an XElement. When I use XElement.Value it strips any HTML that may be in the node.

I know that if I do XElement.ToString() I can keep the HTML, but it also gives me the node tags. Is there any way to extract the content of a Node as is without the HTML being stripped out?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the nodes inside the XElement, like this:

```
node.Nodes().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, n) => sb.Append(n.ToString())).ToString()
```

Or, in .Net 4.0:

```
String.Concat(node.Nodes())
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Makes total sense, when you see it.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

string xml = node.CreateNavigator().InnerXml;
```